# Exception: undefined method `blacklisted_keywords'

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I have the following block of Ruby code within a class:

```
def self.blacklisted_keywords
  %w(acquista acquistiamo acquisto acquistano compro compriamo comprano)
end

private

def item_valid?
  keywords = blacklisted_keywords
end
```

Why can't I call `blacklisted_keywords` without getting: "undefined method `blacklisted_keywords'"? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `blacklisted_keywords` is not an instance method, rather a class method.`keywords = blacklisted_keywords` means ruby looking at it implicitly as `keywords = self.blacklisted_keywords`. That causes an error, as it is not an instance method. Replace `keywords = blacklisted_keywords` as `keywords = self.class.blacklisted_keywords`

Answer (score 0):

Following the answers provided, maybe it would make sense to keep the keywords in a constant if you don't need to mutate them.

```
class Blah
  BLACKLISTED_KEYWORDS = %w(acquista acquistiamo acquisto acquistano compro compriamo comprano)

  private

  def item_valid?
    keywords = BLACKLISTED_KEYWORDS
  end
end
```

Comment: @Severin This doesn't make sense.